# How to set Windows event log "Archive the log when full, do not overwrite events" option enabled with Group Policy

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-event-log

I want to set up my Windows server's event log "Archive the log when full, do not overwrite events" option enabled with GPO.

In my Group Plicy Management Editer, there is no policy option such as "Archive the log when full, do not overwrite events".

I check the policy
"Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Event log > Retention method for application log", and this plicy has only theae options as following,

- Overwrite events by days
- Overwrite events as needed
- Do not overwrite events(clear log manually)

Is there any other way to achieve "Archive the log when full, do not overwrite events" settings enabled with registry or any other option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computer > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Event Log Service > Security - Backup log when full